# Error while importing android project ("Gradle location is incorrect" or "Cause: unexpected end of block data")

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to import Android project in Android Studio and this is where the problem begins:
1) If I set Gradle home and click OK, I get the info: 
[image]

2) And secondly, if I try to run project I get the message:
[image]

Trying both ways result in displaying messages above.
I have GRADLE_HOME, JAVA_HOME set correctly and ANDROID_HOME points to "sdk" directory in android-studio directory.
Much appreciation for answer with the solution.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/21646252/3020568

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I missed to download some build tools for specified android version, arrgh.. Anyway, thank you for your interest and the answers. I am quite new to gradle and Android studio. I have been developing android apps with intellij so far.

That worked for me:
1. Open Android SDK Manager.
2. Make sure that "Build tools ..." libraries are downloaded and it should work properly.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Konklone in my case I had `buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"` in `build.gradle` file, but had only 19.0.3 installed. So downloading 19.0.1 from SDK Manager made things work. (Most likely it would be enough to update `build.gradle` to use 19.0.3)

Answer (score 13):

Point to the folder `<gradle root folder>/libexec`. Things should start working.

Comment: What do you mean? Where we should put this/ can you be more specific please?

Comment: That fixed it.  Ugh, that is so obnoxious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to respond to this cause I had a ton of problems.

what I did was in linux

in terminal

type "which gradle"

if there is a symlink follow this until you see where your gradle is located.

mine was located in the following.

/usr/lib/gradle/4.2/bin/gradle

so now just use

/usr/lib/gradle/4.2/lib is what you want to put in intelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Try to use default gradle wrapper. Android studio will do everything correctly.

Comment: I actually tried every option. I figured out that I have set GRADLE_HOME improperly. Now I get only the message from the second pic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Cause: unexpected end of block data) while importing a project, and resolved by setting ANDROID_HOME. `export ANDROID_HOME=/android_sdk_root_dir`

Answer (score 0):

I had a "Cause: unexpected end of block data" as well. What I did was installing the right SDK version for Android. Check your *build.gradle* file.
In my case I needed API level 18:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
    }
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I went to http://gradle.org/gradle-download/ and downloaded the latest gradle. I then linked my project to the path where i had saved the gradle, and everything worked