# How to set gradle home while importing existing project in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

How to set gradle home while importing existing project in Android studio. While trying to import I need to set up this path. [image]

Comment: [Gradle location is incorrect error while importing ActionBarsherlock in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17623439/6521116)

Answer (score 242, accepted):

The gradle plugin (which contains a bundled version of gradle) should be already installed in *where/you/installed/android-studio*/plugins/gradle so you shouldn't need to manually download it. Depending on the version of Android Studio, that last directory may be  *where/you/installed/android-studio*/gradle/gradle-x.y.z (x.y.z is the version, so check your filesystem for the exact path).

If you intend on doing gradle development outside Android Studio or want a different version, you can download it separately and point it at that path, but if you only want to get Android Studio working with the bundled version, this path should do it.

Comment: The path plugins/gradle is to the gradle plugin, not gradle.

Comment: Is there any differences between them for the purposes of importing projects in Android Studio?

Comment: I think it'd be better to use a real gradle dir. It's wherever you installed it plus "libexec" for me, e.g. `/usr/local/opt/gradle/` (from Homebrew on Mac)

Comment: I just tried this with Android Studio 0.8.0 and it complained about using the plugin directory. I noticed though that gradle seems to be entirely located within the lib subdir, so I then instead pointed Android Studio to where/you/installed/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib and it worked.

Comment: Do not point it to the gradle-plugin but to the gradle-library which is in `.../android-studio/plugins/gradle/**lib**`

Comment: If you point to the gradle-lib as last person commented you will get an error from Android Studio that is not the right folder.

Comment: the directory in this answer was different for me. I used /install/path/to/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.2.1

Comment: @AlexChaffee Could you share the whole path entry you have there. I'm also on OS X + Homebrew. What do you mean by 'plus "libexec"', precisely? IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3, gradle 2.3

Comment: OS X + Homebrew: /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/2.3/libexec/

Comment: Mine was here:   C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2

Answer (score 105):

For Mac OS, you can use the following -

1. `/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec/` or more generically - `path/to/gradle/libexec/` - this is recommended. *(the first path is what's achieved after installing gradle via Homebrew)*
2. `/path/to/android/studio/plugins/gradle` - I don't recommend this because this version of Gradle might be out of date, and Android Studio itself might say it's incompatible.

Comment: Thanks, /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/2.3/libexec/ worked for me. + you might add that your reply has to do with OS X + Homebrew.

Comment: say me: "graddle libexe is not supported, would you like to use graddle wrapper to update automatically ?" i clicked "yes" and alles was ok, it was strange because ; "brew info gradle " give this folder "/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/3.1" but Android Studio does not recognise gradle there

Answer (score 48):

You should be able to find it in

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\Gradle\Gradle 2.2.1
```

(Replace the Gradle version with your actual version)

This is running Windows 7 64-Bit. Android Studio 1.0.2.

Answer (score 38):

OSX (Less han two minutes)

1. Open terminal
2. Check if Gradle installed `gradle --version`, *if so, goto step 4*
3. If not `brew install gradle` *and Goto step 2*
4. Copy `/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec/`
5. Paste it in **Import Project** Window in Android Studio > **Gradle Home**
6. Important, Celebrate!

Answer (score 26):

1. Download Gradle http://www.gradle.org/downloads
2. Install
3. Set Gradle home to the install directory

Comment: how to know the install directory?

Comment: @htafoya how to know which operating system and installation type you use? "Installing manually" should be the easiest on all systems. The "install" directory is the directory where you extract to.

Comment: @htafoya you can follow the official per-OS Gradle instructions found here https://gradle.org/install/#manually

Answer (score 21):

On Linux run: `whereis gradle`.

For me it was `/usr/lib/gradle/1.10`.

Comment: A better option will be to use /usr/lib/gradle/default no to depend on specific version

Answer (score 13):

I ran into same problem. I selected location C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle as Gradle Home

Answer (score 11):

In Ubuntu 14.04 after `$ sudo apt-get install gradle`
I've got

```
$ whereis gradle
gradle: /usr/bin/gradle /usr/bin/X11/gradle /usr/share/gradle /usr/share/man/man1/gradle.1.gz
```

The path to Gradle was `/usr/share/gradle`

Answer (score 8):

For Mac,

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.2
```

Answer (score 4):

Download Gradle as described above, but make sure you download version 1.9 and not the current release (1.11). I just had the same problem and downloaded the current release only to have Android Studio tell me it wasn't supported.

Comment: Gradle plugin 0.9.0 and 0.10.0 both support Android Studio http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Answer (score 4):

On Arch Linux I could not find it, so I added:

```
echo $APP_HOME
```

to /usr/bin/grade (found over `which gradle`)

The Install dir for me was /usr/share/java/gradle/

Comment: Line 68 in the /usr/bin/grade file

Answer (score 3):

For migrating from eclipse to android studio

**(Do not need to specify the Gradle home.)**

1. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, **select the build.gradle file** and click OK.
2. In the following dialog, **leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK**.

Try this for windows users

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/setting-up-android-studio-gradle-windows-7/

Comment: on a mac, this didnt work for me...wouldnt allow me to select the build.gradle file for my project

Answer (score 3):

I tried [byteit101's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753291/1392908) but whether I chose `android-studio-path/plugins/gradle` or `android-studio-path/plugins/gradle/lib` the IDE said it isn't correct.

Then I changed the gradle home to `android-studio-path/gradle/gradle-x.x.x` and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OSX / Linux

```
Step 1: Open terminal :)
Step 2: Open .bash_profile in vim to edit: 
        > vi ~/.bash_profile 
Step 3: Add line: 
        > export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/opt/gradle 
        (for me it was this location, it can be different for u)
Step 4: Add line: 
        > export PATH="$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin" 
        (to export bin directory of gradle)
Step 5: Verify by reopening the terminal or new tab, and check by echoing: 
        > echo $GRADLE_HOME
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux Mint 17 it was

```
/usr/share/gradle
```

for me

Comment: Also works on fedora 22 if gradle has been installed using dnf

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Windows machine, go to the directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\
```

Click the **gradle-4.4** folder from **Android Studio\File\Settings**, and then click the **Apply** button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution on AndroidStudio/Idea for Mac

```
$ env | grep GRADLE
GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/2.6
GRADLE_USER_HOME=/Users/leon/.gradle
```

Answer (score 1):

I used **umake** to install android studio. For me the path was

```
/home/user/.local/share/umake/android/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.14.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to download or specify anything...

Just go to the install Android Studio plugins Path and search for any file like gradle-wrapper-x.xx.jar (x.xx = version number). Copy it to a subfolder of your project root folder named : gradle.

Example : 
  - file found gradle-wrapper-1.12.jar in plugins folder of Android Studio Install's path
  - my project was on D:\android_repo\myProject
  - created a folder into D:\android_repo\myProject\gradle
  - copy gradle-wrapper-1.12.jar to this folder D:\android_repo\myProject\gradle
  - import again my project and no more question about gradle.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows

```
..\AndroidStudio2.0Beta6\android-studio\gradle\gradle-2.10
```

Answer (score 0):

I've stumble across this question, trying to build an Ionic + Cordova app using Gradle from Android Studio installation, rather that installing Gradle separately.

On Centos, the Gradle binary was here:  `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-VERSION-all/CUSTOM_HASH/gradle-VERSION/bin`

So, I've added `export PATH=/home/maxim/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1-all/bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew/gradle-4.1/bin:$PATH` to my `~/.bashrc` and `ionic cordova run android` command worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MacPorts gradle's home is:

```
/opt/local/share/java/gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu default version is `/usr/lib/gradle/default`.
In case of update, you don't need to reassign link in idea/studio.

Answer (score 0):

For OSX, if going to Finder, navigate to this category: **/usr/local/opt/** if you do not see gradle folder, install your grandle version manually:

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip

If you are looking for specific Gradle version, simply change the version number from the zip links above, unzip and add that in the Gradle folder **/usr/local/opt/gradle**

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it was

> C:/Android Studio/jre

Answer (score 0):

For my issue, I realised the `java HOME` was not set on my M2 mac machine.
I set the java version via HomeBrew.

Then the gradle commands started to work fine