# Android studio Import Module: Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse Project

Tags: android-studio, android-library, android-studio-import

I was trying to import `ViewPagerIndicator` Library however they show this.

How to solve this problem ?

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTxQ6.png)

Comment: try this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646252/how-to-set-gradle-home-while-importing-existing-project-in-android-studio

Comment: how would you solved this isue?

Answer (score 4):

You can import a viewpageindicator.
that project created in eclipse so can not find gradle file
when you import module that only on same platform.

like in my case i was import facebook sdk 4.7.0 but give same error "Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse Project"
so i download new sdk 4.1.0 which completely for android studio related
and i import easily.

if your project was in eclipse platform so
you need to import as a eclipse project
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKvw1.png)

i hope you understand