# Android studio gradle home path

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hi friends i want to set  gradle home path in android studio. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753291  according to this answer  there should be a gradle folder in android studio folder . But i don't have it can anyone please tell me why. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The Gradle plugin is only a support system for android to get used to gradle, especially in your case you have to set GRADLE_HOME in your system environment variables. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

But usally there would be a gradle wrapper if you haven't installed gradle, it should be inside your project folder.
you can use it by calling `gradlew` inside your project folder.

So you have to [download](https://gradle.org/) Gradle and install it.

then set the GRADLE_HOME variable if not set.
https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

I would not suggest setting the gradle home inside your android studio folder.

Comment: Actually my problem is my new files are not updating to SVN .I have changed my laptop.so am trying all possible ways.performing VCS commit is not completing.

Comment: Good for you Android Studio is a lightweighted version of IntelliJ, it has a powerful VCS integration, you should try it https://dzone.com/articles/version-control-of-android-studio-project-via-svn

Comment: Yes tried already. did'nt work. all files changed color from red to green but they are not adding to repository.

Comment: No offense intended did you push your changes ?

Comment: Yes . problem came there only.performing VCS commit never completing.

Comment: Done  when i commit from project folder instead of doing it from android studio.

Answer (score 3):

You can find it inside the plugins folder